# Visual Studio debugger closes upon receiving input from Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, debugging

I have the following simple piece of code:

```
namespace Ex04
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the index-character generator.);
            Console.WriteLine("Please write your name:");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("The second letter of your name is \"{0}\", the fourth letter is \"{1}\", while the sixth letter is \"{2}\".", name[1], name[3], name[5]);
        }
    }
}
```

When entering the debugger from Visual Studio the command prompt will open asking for an input from the user. Although upon entering any input the command prompt simply continues to execute the statements and the command prompt will close without showing the execution stepwise as expected. The project is correctly created as a "Console App".

Could anybody help out in identifying the issue here? How do i 'run' the program in debugging mode from start till finish? Is the marked statement from where entering the debugger (F10) is done important?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the index-character generator.");`

Comment: Add a `Console.ReadKey()` in the end to keep the debugging window open if it is closing.

Comment: Got it - helps with keeping the command prompt open. After starting it holds the command prompt after debugging open, but I am missing a feature where I am being shown the execution statement by statement. Is this not possible in the debugger or does it only flag errors? I know the JetBrains IntelliJ IDE has something like I mentioned.

Comment: You need to add a break point and run it in `Debug` mode. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) should help you.